# How to check if current post or category is descendant of certain category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to know how to check if current single post or current category is child of certain category with any depth.

For example:

`Cat1` > `Cat2` > `Cat3` > `Cat4` > `Post1`

Check if `Post1` is child of `Cat1`

and check if `Cat4` is child of `Cat1`

Answer (score 1):

This function returns `true` in the situations above. and `false` otherwise.

```
<?php
function post_or_category_descendant_of( $category_id ) {
    if( is_category() && ( is_category( $category_id ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( $category_id, get_queried_object() ) ) ) {
        return true;

    } else if( is_single() ){

        $post_id = get_queried_object()->id;
        $post_categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

        $post_cat_ids = array();

        foreach( $post_categories as $pc ) {
            $post_cat_ids[] = $pc->cat_ID;
        }

        $args = array( 'child_of' => $category_id, 'fields' => 'ids' );
        $target_cat_ids = get_categories( $args );
        $target_cat_ids[] = $category_id;

        if( array_intersect( $post_cat_ids, $target_cat_ids ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tofandel because it is not so simple !